# Deploying Silent Arduino Install Using SCCM

Tags: powershell, sccm, silent-installer

So! This is a little strange but to keep it simple and short I work as lower technician and have aspirations to work as a net admin / sys admin dont know still up in the air. So this question is practical in sense as it would aid me in my work but outside my control because I already received a no and or we just lack the resources.

So I was attempting to prepare a silent install for the Arduino software using SCCM (thats one tool we use for software deployment, mostly the main one). The issue we ran into (we meaning other people on the internet trying to accomplish the same thing) where you had to manually confirm/trust driver installs (three of them at the end). I will link the article here to provide more info.

So I ended up extracting the trusted certificates on a dummy machine to a folder and they recommended just pointing to that folder during the install and make it a dependency so that it wouldnt install without it. My question is how difficult once you have the .exe installer and trusted certs is it to implement into SCCM ? and would there have been a way to deploy this using a script in powershell ? I am just trying to wrap my head around the possibilities. I understand there may be a lot of vague info in here which may hurt the responses I get (if any at all) but ! I must try so I can fine tune my question asking process to increase my chances in the future ! right ?

Thanks to anyone who took time to read this, I appreciate your time !

Link: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=304784.0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this question would be more likely to be answered on Server Fault or Super User as the question is not about programming. With that said likely your certs should be pushed with Group Policy and then installer through SCCM.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback ! I will try posting my question there and try and refine this post a little bit more.